# Symfony2 form entity preferred_choices set selected values

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm having dificulties trying to set on my form the selected values on the preferred choices.

I have a class calendar that can have multiple taxes:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('possibledigits')
        ->add('notes')
        ->add('autogenerateyear', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
        ->add('calendartaxes', null, array(
              'required' => false,
              'multiple' => true, 
              'expanded' => true
            ))    
    ;
}
```

The relation is many to many:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CalendarTax", indexBy="name", inversedBy="calendarios")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="contable_schedule_taxes_relation")
 */ 
private $calendartaxes;
```

What I was going to do is to try to get the entity of the form and try to get the selected taxes. But I don't know if that is the correct way to do it.
Is there a more elegant way to do it?

I'm using symfony 2.3.

Regards.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to have values from CalendarTax as checkboxes? What do you call preferred choices? So far, it seems you don't have any values at all in your field, let alone preferred choices.

Comment: I try to show the one that been selected first and then the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a relationship set up betwween Calendarios and CalendarTax

so before you create the form ... do

```
$calendarios = new CalendarIOS();
$calendartax = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('NamBundle:CalendarTax')->find($calendar_tax_id);
$calendarios->addCalendarTax($calendartax);
```

now when you send the entity over to the formbuilder...you will have that perticular calendartax checked... :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use the preferred_choices of the choice.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $calendario = $builder->getData();
    $taxesId = array();
    foreach($calendario->getCalendartaxes() as $tax){
      $taxesId[] = $tax;
    }
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('possibledigits')
        ->add('notes')
        ->add('autogenerateyear', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
        ->add('calendartaxes', null, array(
              'required' => false,
              'multiple' => true, 
              'expanded' => true,
              'preferred_choices' => $taxesId,
            ))    
    ;
}
```

Making one more query and getting the calendar of the form builder.
The comment given by @Hakim was the one that put me on the right path.

Thanks!